# Непонятная замена ключа в массиве $_FILES

Tags: php

На сервер отправляется POST запрос с файлом:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost:8100' --form 'File 1.txt=@"./file.txt"'
```

Первой строчкой в скрипте выводится дамп `$_FILES`:

```
die(var_dump($_FILES));
```

Содержимое:

```
array(1) {
  ["File_1_txt"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "file.txt"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "text/plain"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpWwGevM"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
```

Вопрос: почему в качестве ключа отправляется `File 1.txt`, а в массиве `$_FILES` это становится `File_1_txt` и как это можно исправить?

PS. Если запустить с опцией `--trace` (`curl --trace - --request POST 'http://localhost:8100' --form 'File 1.txt=@"./file.txt"'`), лог такой:

```
...
0020: 33 36 30 63 31 62 34 33 62 63 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 360c1b43bc..Cont
0030: 65 6e 74 2d 44 69 73 70 6f 73 69 74 69 6f 6e 3a ent-Disposition:
0040: 20 66 6f 72 6d 2d 64 61 74 61 3b 20 6e 61 6d 65  form-data; name
0050: 3d 22 46 69 6c 65 20 31 2e 74 78 74 22 3b 20 66 ="File 1.txt"; f
0060: 69 6c 65 6e 61 6d 65 3d 22 66 69 6c 65 2e 74 78 ilename="file.tx
0070: 74 22 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 t"..Content-Type
...
```

То есть однозначно отправляется `"File 1.txt"`, а PHP на этапе парсинга запроса производит замену входных данных.

PS2.

То же самое для `curl --request POST 'http://localhost:8100' --data-urlencode 'foo bar=baz'`

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump($_POST);
die;
```

Выводит

```
string(11) "foo bar=baz"
array(1) {
  ["foo_bar"]=>
  string(3) "baz"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464444/php-html-how-to-retain-spaces-in-form-input-names

Comment: Вот нашел правильный https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092398/post-spaces-converted-in-underscores

Comment: @splash58 спасибо. А можно от пыха добиться ожидаемое поведение без этого? Я посмотрел различные настройки php.ini, но ничего такого там не нашел. Похоже что это чисто пыховская какая-то особенность.

Comment: Судя по второму ответу, это стратегия поведения.  сделайте массив - будет вам счастье :)

Comment: @splash58 просто огромедное спасибо. Так и сделаю. Если оформите в виде ответа, я его приму

Comment: Скорее надо закрыть, как дубль :)

Comment: @splash58 да, но по правилам, enSO - это отдельная тема. А мы тут развиваем ru. Ну и плюс в карму другим способом не поставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема чисто PHP из-за легаси-кода.

Была функция `import_request_variables` которая создает из суперглобальных массивов POST/GET/Cookie глобальные переменные. Но переменные в PHP не могут содержать пробелы, точки и другие символы. Поэтому происходит их замена на _.

Функции уже нет, а такое поведение осталось.

> Точки и пробелы в именах переменных преобразуется в знаки подчёркивания. Например, `<input name="a.b" />` станет `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.

Проблема решается оборачиванием в массив: `foo bar=baz` => `data[foo bar]=baz`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092398/post-spaces-converted-in-underscores

Спасибо @splash58 за наводку.